# Editing a remote MediaWiki site locally (offline)

Tags: mediawiki, markup, offline

I've become familiar with MediaWiki for various projects and now I much prefer its markup over using a word-processor/html/latex/restructured-text etc.

The thing is that some of the servers I edit on are quite slow, or I may not even want the document to end up online.

So my question is: Short of setting up my own webserver and running a MediaWiki instance, what's a way to edit MediaWiki markup and view locally?

Is there a tool or application which does this?

The formatting does not have to be a 100% match but I would want to be able to copy and paste between this and online MediaWiki docs with minimal editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/wiki/): make a local .html page to preview your edits in real time.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried to use this but I couldn't find how to enable mediawiki syntax. Even after looking over sources and online docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to edit the occasional page, you could try LibreOffice, with the libreoffice-wiki-publisher plugin: you can just paste the entire article into a new document, save it locally, edit it and then use the "Send to... wiki" menu to save the wikitext on the remote page.

Offline editing of MediaWiki is definitely a problem to solve; the best place where to discuss it is probably the offline-l mailing list, as [Kiwix](http://kiwix.org/) needs a solution too.

Answer (score 0):

To give an answer to my own question, SoloWiki is an application which fits the bill:
http://solowiki.sourceforge.net

Though I used it a few times, it's not updated since 0.3 in 2010 and the output is limited to headings, bullets, numbering (from what I can tell).

Just including this answer here for completeness, I don't think it's an especially good option.